# How to write the parsed json in asynctask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am working on app which parse data from URL with adding parameter username and pwd and update it, parsing is completed but I am not able to update or write/post back to server.

```
private class abc extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    String response = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost p1 = new HttpPost("Url");

        List<NameValuePair>data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);               
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName", "abc"));
            data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "def"));

            try {
                  p1.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
                  HttpResponse execute = client.execute(p1);
                  InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                  BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                  String s = "";
                  while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                  }             

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
        return response;
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        JSONObject inf = new JSONObject(result);
        int id = inf.getInt("UserID");
        String username = inf.getString("UserName");

        TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t1.setText("user id :"+id+"\n"+"user name :"+UserName);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?  *I'm confused*

Comment: my question is like parsing user information from url and update it, i am done with parsing but what next ?

Comment: to server back, i need to update username and password how can i do plz help

Comment: Is still not clear what your asking. From the above code you are passing the username and password and doing a POST to the "url". The you get the Json response. If you want to update it again call the Async task again with the new values. Not really sure what exactly you need.

Comment: actually first i want the parse the json data from url like username id pwd etc, after parsing i need to update/change those username id pwd,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of update

```
private class abcupdate extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
String response = "";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost p1 = new HttpPost("Urlforupdate");

    List<NameValuePair>data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);               
        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName", "abc"));
        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "def"));
        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", "userIdyouwant"));
        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("datapt1", "pqrs"));


        try {
              p1.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
              HttpResponse execute = client.execute(p1);
              InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
              BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
              String s = "";
              while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
              }             

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    return response;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
super.onPostExecute(result);
//do what you need wwith response
//maybe just send success or failure of update from server
}
```

Hope this has cleared everything

Comment: no this one is not working i already tried , by addings more params its still showing the data only its not updating

Comment: If the data you sent to the server is showing there, then the part above is correct as it is meant only to send the data. After getting data on the server, you need to write a query to update your server database. Only then will the update take place. Are yoou doing this?

Comment: for example i am using this url "http://114.143.190.99:81/Feeds/api/Authentication/Authenticate" with ("UserName", "paresh"));("Password", "paresh")); , i am getting their data id and more now i need to change the id how can i do ??

Comment: Please do the following:

Comment: "114.143.190.99:81/Feeds/api/Update" could be a new route you define for accepting requests for updating data. Now in the logic for this route, make the update query!

Comment: Thanks buddy actually it's a server issue

Answer (score 2):

Pass Your Parameter in doInBackground with username and password and also userId
username and password is your current username and password(like get edittext value) and call asyntask with post method

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your question completely.

If you want to update the data on the server based on the data received, you could do it before sending the response back right.
Why do you want to make another request and update the data.

Updating data on the server will be in your server side logic and not android code.
If this is not what you want, please explain the question a bit more clearly ;-)

Comment: ok then how can i post data to server , because on setentity i am already posting username and pwd

Comment: you are posting data to the server, when you are putting keyvalue pairs. You just need to access this data on the server side

Comment: after putting username and pwd i am getting all data , now i want to change userid and remaining things , without changing the username and pwd. can i use outputstream writer or jsonwriter ?

Comment: so, after you get the response and retrieving the userid and other tthings, you need to update the server data?? am i getting it right? could you just post the total flow you need here

Comment: server only except two params username and pwd with this two params they send the data of that user, now i need to update that data , how can i do ??

Comment: Just make another post request to the server with more name value pairs containing the userid and other data points and run a update query on the database there. Handle this request on another endpoint. (ex: /getid for initial one and /update for this one) Use the username and pswd to identify which entry to update. Hope this solved everything;-)

Comment: will you please give me a little bit example of that please

Comment: for the server side or the android part?